# Xcode 9 Debugger: How to change the highlight color for the current line when debugging

Tags: xcode, debugging, editor, syntax-highlighting, xcode9

when debugging in Xcode 9, the highlight color is too dim.

i have tried the various highlight colors in the "Preferences" "Fonts & Colors", but none seems to change the background highlight color for this line.